# How to use Simple HTML Dom to get text next to image element?

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom parser to get a text that next to img tag from an HTML string like:

**HTML**

```
<tr>                                  
  <td>
    <img alt="Checkbox checked, changed" src="/Images/crd_pgm_RedlineCheckSelected.gif">My TEXT HERE
  </td>   
</tr>
```

**I tried writing the belo code:**

```
<?php

  foreach($html->find('img') as $element) {
    $plantext = $element->next_sibling()->plaintext;
    echo $plantext;
  }

?>
```

But it shows NULL everytime. How can I **scrape** this text?

Comment: $plantext = $element->plaintext;

Comment: @BCM , I tried that as well but it returns an empty value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments of [simple_html_dom.php](https://github.com/Wikia/simplehtmldom/blob/master/simple_html_dom.php) it states this text:

> Paperg add the text and plaintext to the selectors for the find
>   syntax.  plaintext implies text in the innertext of a node.  text
>   implies that the tag is a text node.

When I add  `text` to the selector for `find` I get the text

```
foreach($html->find('img text') as $element) {
    echo $element->plaintext;
}
```

Output

```
My TEXT HERE
```